# Why is the URL dispatcher not redirecting as well as updating the database?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple form in Django that takes inputs as username, email, password and adds them to database. Now when I click on submit button the URL dispatcher is not redirecting as well as updating the database. Here is my code:

**loginForm\urls.py ( loginForm as project ):**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include from django.contrib import admin

app_name = 'authentication'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^authentication/', include('authentication.urls',namespace="authentication")),
    ]
```

**authentication\urls.py ( authentication as app ):**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.SignIn, name="sign_in"),
    url(r'^register/$',views.Register, name="register"),
    ]
```

**sign_in.html** :

```
{% extends 'authentication/base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> Register </legend>
                <from method="post" action="{% url 'authentication:register' %}" >
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div >
                        <input name="username" type="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
                        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <br> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-defaul"> Submit </button>
                </from>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import users

def SignIn(request):
    return render(request,'authentication/sign_in.html')

def Register(request):
    register = users()
    register.username = request.POST['username']
    register.email = request.POST['email']
    register.password = request.POST['password']
    register.save()
    return render(request,'authentication/profile.html',{'username': register.username })
```

Comment: Have you tried adding logging statements to the `SignIn` and `Register` views to make sure they're being invoked?

Comment: In your template the `<form>` tag is mispelled as `<from>`.

Comment: On which URL you are trying to redirect after successful register.?

Comment: Also your registration view should test the request method, a successful POST should be followed by a redirect, your registration system is totally unsafe (unencrypted password....), and your namings do not respect usual python and django conventions (class names should be capitalized, model class names should be singular, function names should be all_lower_with_underdscores)

Comment: i don't want to use any built-in functions or anything i just wanna to learn on my own @mike

Comment: still not working @bruno

Comment: profile: {% extends 'authentication/base.html' %}

{% block body %}

    <h1> You are registered as {{ username }} </h1>

{% endblock %}

Comment: @Ahtisham What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Ahtisham - I'm not sure what "i don't want to use any built-in functions or anything i just wanna to learn on my own" means in context to my question. Using logging to debug and introspect the subtle behaviors of your code epitomizes learning on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestly update your view as :

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import users

def SignIn(request):
    return render(request,'authentication/sign_in.html')

def Register(request):
    register = users()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register.username = request.POST['username']
        register.email = request.POST['email']
        register.password = request.POST['password']
        register.save()
        return redirect('/your_new_url')
    return render(request,'authentication/profile.html',{'username': register.username })
```

And secondly update your HTML template code to fucntion the form as :

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'authentication:register' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div >
        <input name="username" type="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-defaul"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: It worked but i am confused in views you said to " return redirect(...) " and then again call return render(...) but how does it work ?? i mean you can return from a function only once right ??

Comment: @Ahtisham yeah one execution at a time, but you need to understand that when the request.method == 'POST': is true only then return redirect will work, in all other cases, return render will work.

Comment: Its asking for email

Comment: check your email :) and hey why don't i get redirected to profile.html page i     get this error :      Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/profile.html

Comment: @Ahtisham Check your email